# mercurial TortoiseHg ошибка 255

Tags: ubuntu, apache, контроль-версий, mercurial, tortoise-hg

.Добрый день. При попытке залить проект под контроль версий, выдает ошибку 255.
Если заливать файлы под контроль версий на сервер поэтапно по 2-3 файла, то -  заливается норм, когда  больше файлов пытаешься добавить в коммит,то возникает эта ошибка. Причем на другой сервер нормально все заливается сразу скопом. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Данные сервера:
Apache 2.4.41,
PHP 7.4.3,
MySQL  Ver 8.0.22-0,
NodeJS v15.8.0,
Samba,
ubuntu 20.04

[image: error 255]

Текст ошибки

```
    ** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.0.2)
** Extensions loaded: tortoisehg.util.hgcommands, tortoisehg.util.partialcommit, tortoisehg.util.pipeui, tortoisehg.util.win32ill, tortoisehg.util.hgdispatch
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.0.2)
** Extensions loaded: tortoisehg.util.hgcommands, tortoisehg.util.partialcommit, tortoisehg.util.pipeui, tortoisehg.util.win32ill, tortoisehg.util.hgdispatch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 50, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 99, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 225, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 376, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 384, in _callcatch
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 167, in callcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 367, in _runcatchfunc
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1021, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 756, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1030, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1018, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1680, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 5300, in serve
  File "mercurial\server.pyo", line 147, in runservice
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 405, in run
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 346, in serve
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 319, in serveone
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 303, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 225, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 376, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 384, in _callcatch
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 167, in callcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 367, in _runcatchfunc
  File "tortoisehg\util\hgdispatch.pyo", line 23, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1021, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 756, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1030, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1018, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1680, in check
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1680, in check
  File "tortoisehg\util\partialcommit.pyo", line 34, in partialcommit
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1680, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1647, in commit
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1722, in _docommit
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyo", line 2434, in commit
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1720, in commitfunc
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 177, in wrapper
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 2548, in commit
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 177, in wrapper
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 2622, in commitctx
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 2434, in _filecommit
  File "mercurial\filelog.pyo", line 135, in add
  File "mercurial\filelog.pyo", line 106, in addrevision
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 1905, in addrevision
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 1916, in addrawrevision
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 544, in _indexfp
  File "mercurial\store.pyo", line 571, in __call__
  File "mercurial\vfs.pyo", line 420, in __call__
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 2314, in makedirs
WindowsError: [Error 50] : '\\\\vsrvdev1\\web\\sez\\dev\\.hg/store\\data/~f4~fb~e2'
cmdserver: процесс завершился неожиданно с кодом 255
```

Comment: Начните с того, чтобы взять версию посвежее.

Comment: имеете  ввиду версию меркуриала?

Comment: У меня вот TortoiseHG 5.7.1 с таким же меркуриалом (как там написано). У вас на скрине меркуриал 5.0.2. И с такой проблемой я сталкивался, но комитить сразу очень много файлов нужно редко и легко обойти закомитив частями и слить.

Comment: ну в проекте ~200 файлов и комитить по 2-3, это слишком суровый костыль, уверен это проблема на стороне сервера, потому что на другой нормально залетает полностью проект. может просто уже кто сталкивался и подскажет где в найстроках что поменять

Comment: На стороне какого сервера? это DVCS и тем более меркуриал - у которого все клоны равнозначны. Ну по 2-3 мало. По 50-100 нормально. У вас явно пишет, что проблема при создании папок внутри .hg. Обычно такая проблема (и не только в питоне) если диск, где лежит проект, не является физическим томом. Иногда помогало дать полные права доступа (не смотря на то, что имеющихся достаточно). Но это под виндой. Под другими осями не использую.

Answer (score 0):

Дорогие ленивые дети!

1. Читайте в traceback, что именно написано, в последней (в выводе) строке содержится самая первая хронологическая ошибка

> File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 2314, in makedirs WindowsError: [Error
> 50] : '\\vsrvdev1\web\sez\dev\.hg/store\data/~f4~fb~e2'
> cmdserver: процесс завершился неожиданно с кодом 255

Если процесс на сетевом диске не может что-то сделать, то надо идти к умному человеку (админу сервера) и проверять права пользователя, под которым работает процесс (Mercurial или нет - неважно)

2. Mercurial - система для работы с *локальными данными*, сетевые драйвы (любые) как хранилище репозитория в нем **крайне не рекомендованы** разработчиками, ну а расшаренный репо, в который идут параллельные независимые коммиты (несмотря на всю его, Меркуриала, транзакционность) - это не выстрел в ногу, это сразу в голову

Резюме: это не ошибка, исправлять это надо постановкой нормального рабочего процесса, **естественного для DVCS** - local commit, push|pull, merge

Учите матчасть, короче, бойцы!